# Importing a cookie by calling on an external Cookie txt file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, mobile

Is it possible to do this:

Visit a webpage on a Desktop browser 
Export the cookie from said webpage to a .txt file,
Also save the webpage as an html file,
Add a jquery or javascript script to the html webpage file,
Upload html webpage, along with .txt cookie file to a server,
Get your phone, visit the link that connects you to the html file on the server
and have it automatically call on the .txt file to import the cookie in a mobile
environment and use the cookies.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds far too abstract. If you can save a file on server then all this could be done through server programming language code.

Comment: How would you save an html document that contains cookies to a server, then access it at a later date with the cookie still in tact?

Comment: An html file doesn't have cookies in it. That's not how cookies work. You would need to store separately the file and the cookie key/value pair in order to access it on another device

Comment: And how exactly would I do that? I know html, css and a php.. But I am trying to figure out how to connect to the webpage with the cookie from a mobile device. Please help?

Comment: Starting to think all this might be related to a site you don't control. If that's true and cookie is `httpOnly` cookie it is not possible. If it is site you do control will need to use some sort of login system to be able to match user to different devices

Comment: @charlietfl I do own and control this website. Is there any way you could contact me via skype?  I will pay you if you'll help me.. Please? My skype is jaguartrials and my name is Tommy. Thank you so much.